# Create a trigger in postgres that updates a FIFO

Tags: linux, postgresql

Suppose,I have a FIFO name test in directory temp, Then How can I create a trigger in postgreSQl database which updates a FIFO when the value of a J-son data is matched?

Comment: Have you try any thing

Comment: I think it can be done in the following way:                                      1) Create a function and use system command in it 2) then call a trigger and associate the function with it. The trigger can be initiated after the every instance of insert  3 ) No try inserting a record in the field.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done in the following way:

used language plpgsql

**1)** Create a function and use system command in it .

**2)** call a trigger and associate the function with it. The trigger can be initiated after the every instance of insert.

**3)** Now try inserting a record in the field.

Second Approach is as follows:
Use listen and notify so that a daemon will listen to the asynchronous messages which will be sent as and when on any database activity.

I tried the following and got it working : 
a) created a function and registered it as trigger and use notify table name in it.

b)  create a trigger which executes the function whenever the condition is satisfied.

c) now whenever we insert in database there is a notification being sent to the daemon which listens to it and can take appropriate action.